# Web scraping with python, getting none when img tag name exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

```
r = requests.get("https://amindi.org/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
dedassheveci = soup.find_all('div', class_="col-4")
print(dedassheveci[1])
```

'it returns next:'

```
<div class="col-4">
<img aria-hidden="true" class="icon-DS-EntryPoint1-1 tippy" data-tippy-content="უმეტესად 
მოწმენდილი" role="presentation" src="/img/weather/34.png" style="width: 40px;"/>
</div>
```

'when I'm trying to get data-tippy-content name it returns none
how can I fix it?'

Comment: _trying to get data-tippy-content name_ There isn't any code here that does this.  It's hard to diagnose errors when you don't show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Select your element more specific or check if there is an attribute `data-tippy-content` - This `css selector` is selecting all images with the specific attribute:

```
soup.select('img[data-tippy-content]')
```

#### Example

Getting the values of all these `data-tippy-content` with list comprehension:

```
r = requests.get("https://amindi.org/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
[x['data-tippy-content'] for x in soup.select('img[data-tippy-content]')]
```

#### Output

```
['ღრუბლიანი', 'ღრუბლიანი', 'ღრუბლიანი', 'ღრუბლიანი', 'ღრუბლიანი']
```